# When running stack build for with scalpel as a dependency, I encounter exitFailure1

Tags: haskell, stack

Currently using stack to build the project with only `base` and `scalpel` as my 2 dependencies.

This is the error log:

```
2019-03-31 19:47:34.154259: [info] curl-1.3.8: configure
2019-03-31 19:47:34.154652: [debug] Run process within /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/: /home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc-8.6.4 --make -odir /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup -hidir /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup -i -i. -package=Cabal-2.4.0.1 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/pkgdb /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/Setup.hs /home/noel/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup -threaded
2019-03-31 19:47:35.351994: [debug] Process finished in 1197ms: /home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc-8.6.4 --make -odir /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup -hidir /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup -i -i. -package=Cabal-2.4.0.1 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/pkgdb /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/Setup.hs /home/noel/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup -threaded
2019-03-31 19:47:35.352206: [debug] Run process within /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/: /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --with-ghc=/home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/pkgdb --libdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/lib --bindir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/bin --datadir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/share --libexecdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/etc --docdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --htmldir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --haddockdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=containers=containers-0.6.0.1 -fnew-base
Progress 1/3

--  While building package curl-1.3.8 using:
      /tmp/stack5290/curl-1.3.8/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --with-ghc=/home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/noel/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/pkgdb --libdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/lib --bindir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/bin --datadir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/share --libexecdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/etc --docdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --htmldir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --haddockdir=/home/noel/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-13.14/8.6.4/doc/curl-1.3.8 --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=containers=containers-0.6.0.1 -fnew-base
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Please see the answer here, I think we had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259602/stack-install-curl-fails